# Uploading the HTML for a DIV into a database field

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to save the HTML for a DIV into a database field and I'm wondering the best way to upload it.  There's doesn't seem to be much difference between 1) putting the html for the DIV into a form input or textarea and submitting the form or 2) doing something with Ajax.  Or perhaps there's a technique crafted specifically to do  what I want to do. I'm just wondering how you guys would do this.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't very specific. You want to make an editor to upload HTML code? What exactly do you want to do in more detail.

Comment: This sounds a little bit backwards. Generally speaking, a server produces HTML from data it has access to, why would the server then need to save that HTML from the client back to the server? re: *"how you guys would do this"*. I wouldn't, if at all possible, I'd instead ensure that the **data** relevant for the production of the HTML is saved, while the means to convert that data to a HTML "view" is a coding concern. Perhaps you could offer a broader picture of what you're trying to accomplish? It sounds unconventional, maybe you're trying to go about it the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, it is backwards.  This is where the page is created, not where it is downloaded.  This is a rudimentary page builder.  The user developing the page enters some text, drags an image, etc., into a area that is wrapped in a DIV.  When the user clicks outside the DIV it is judged to be finished and the DIV HTML that was created needs to be saved in a database field. So the click handler that detects the click outside the DIV will run the submit/Ajax/etc code to upload the data to some PHP.

Comment: In that case, the options you've already suggested would be sufficient. It doesn't really need or warrant anything more *special*. Just... send the data to the server.

Comment: Thanks. (The forum software requires me to add 8 more words, though I just wanted to say thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with simple ajax call,

```
 var d = $("#YourDivId").html();
    $.ajax({
          url:"saveDivHtml.php",
          type:"post",
          data : { DivHtml : d},
          success:function(){
            alert("html saved");
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

typically, you'd be better off actually using a form element to capture data. like placing that content in a textarea field, for example.

also, the difference between sending the content via ajax or via traditional postback is really just a matter of the user experience you're after.

Comment: Again, you can't just say thanks here. You have to do it with 15 characters.  Thanks.

Comment: Just curious.  How did my question get marked -2, and why?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But presumably the commenters up top may have. Here's some things that you could improve about this question. You wrote `"I'd like to save the HTML for a DIV into a database field and I'm wondering the best way to upload it."` First of all, thats not what "uploading" is. You shouldn't be ripping html from a `div` as a data input source, and you didn't mention *why* you think should be doing this. If you'd let us address the task at a more general level, you would have gotten a much better answer. Since you didn't ask it that way, they consider this a low quality question

Comment: First, thank you, Kristian, for your comment. But . . . "saving the HTML for a DIV into a database field" is exactly what you should be doing if you're making a site builder, and I explained in my second post that that's what I was doing. And I can't think right now of a better word for moving data from a client machine to a server than "uploading."